# Timer intterupt Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, timer

I hope this isn't a repeat question, I did my research on the node API documentation pages. 
I have called a timer into play in one of my scripts.

```
 setInterval(function,10000);
```

Now, somewhere down the line, I want the continued execution of the timer to stop.

[here is the unref() call I will refer to in a minute](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_unref)

I have seen example scripts where people will format in this sort of way.

```
var timer = setInterval(function,10000);
....
.... 
// when they want to stop the timer, they run 
timer.unref();
```

This did not work for me, I received a undefined for the .unref
Is this sort of thing impossible? or is there a way for me to stop the timer.

Comment: `.unref()` has nothing to do with stopping the timer.  It just tells node.js that you don't want to keep a process running if the only thing that is still running is that timer.

Answer (score 3):

If using:

```
var timer = setInterval(function() { }, 10000);
```

You can use the `clearInterval` function:

```
clearInterval(timer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `clearInterval`

```
var timer = setInterval(function,10000);
....
.... 
clearInterval(timer);
```